# How to add a helper method to a typeORM entity?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to add a helper method to one of my Entity classes but I'm getting an error message. My entity:

```
import { Entity, PrimaryColumn, Column } from 'typeorm'

@Entity('accounts')
class Account {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  username: string

  @Column({ name: 'firstname' })
  firstName: string

  @Column({ name: 'lastname' })
  lastName: string

  public fullName() : string {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
  }
}
```

When I try to call `account.fullName()` I get the following error message:

`"account.fullName" is not a function`

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add the `get` keyword and call it using property syntax.

```ts
import { Entity, PrimaryColumn, Column } from 'typeorm'

@Entity('accounts')
class Account {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  username: string

  @Column({ name: 'firstname' })
  firstName: string

  @Column({ name: 'lastname' })
  lastName: string

  public get fullName() : string {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you want to call it with a parameter?

Comment: @BurakGavas you can change the `get` keyword to `set` and that's all.

Comment: Is this as per the best practices/ or, are we allowed to do this without ensuring anything breaks (silently)? Would migrations work properly ?

Comment: Does it work with typeorm 0.3.17? Do I need to call the function manually?