# How to keep helper methods after join in Typeorm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, typescript, typeorm

I have 2 entities

```
@Entity()
class UserEntity {
  @OneToOne()
  book: BookEntity;
}
```

and

```
@Entity()
class BookEntity {
 public myCustomMethod(): boolean {
  return true;
 }
}
```

When I join `UserEntity` and `BookEntity` I lose `myCustomMethod` and calling it like `user.book.myCustomMethod` throws `myCustomMethod is not a function`.

Basically I think the join fills `user.book` as plain javascript object and not `new BookEntity()`.

Is there anyway to keep it?

Comment: Seems like a silly solution, but have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050659/how-to-add-a-helper-method-to-a-typeorm-entity ?

Comment: @DemiPixel yes I have tried. It of course doesn't work cause Typeorm does not even call `new`. But fill the data with plain object.